# Как получить номер элемента в массиве по нажатию на маркер в google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Имеется массив:

```
var markersData = [
            {
                lat: 55.672660,     // Широта
                lng: 52.28105,    // Долгота
                name: "Название 1", 
                address:"Адрес 1"
            },
            {
                lat: 55.6783855,
                lng: 52.2907,
                name: "Название 2",
                address:"Адрес 2"
            }
        ];
```

Перебор в цикле до создания маркера:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++){
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i].lat, markersData[i].lng);
                var name = markersData[i].name;
                var address = markersData[i].address;
                // Добавляем маркер с информационным окном
                addMarker(latLng, name, address);
            }
```

Функция создания маркера и действие при нажатии на маркер:

```
function addMarker(latLng, name, address) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: name
            });
            // Отслеживаем клик по нашему маркеру
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                alert(markersData); 
            });     
        }
```

Как при нажатии на маркер, вывести порядковый номер выбранного элемента из массива?

Пояснения:
В массиве элемент "название 1" имеет порядковый номер 0, а "название 2", порядковый номер 1.
При нажатии на маркер, мне нужно вывести:

> Вы нажали на маркер, порядковый номер в массиве N.

Пробовал `alert(markersData);`, не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не много переработал добавление

```
function addMarker(latLng, name, address) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: name
            });
            // Отслеживаем клик по нашему маркеру
              $.each(marker, function(i,e){
                 google.maps.event.addListener(e, 'click', function() {
                   alert(i);
                });
            });  
        }
```